# Typescript rendering via map error: Excessive stack depth comparing types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a project structured:

```
export interface Project{
    id: String,
    title: String,
    description: String,
    image?: any,
    languages: String[]
}
```

and when I try to map over the languages array like:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { multipleProjects } from '../../test/projects'
import { Project as ProjectType } from '../../assets/types/types'

export default function Project() {
    const router = useRouter()
    const { id } = router.query
    const [project, setProject] = useState<ProjectType>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const _project = multipleProjects.find(p => p.id === id)
        if (_project) setProject(_project)
    }, [])

    if (!project) return "No project"
    return (
        <div className="h-screen def-background pt-16">
            <Head>
                <title>Project: </title>
            </Head>
            <div className="flex w-8/12 mx-auto mb-auto mt-24 flex-col justify-center items-center text-gray-200 font-mono">
                <p className="text-center text-3xl font-bold tracking-wide text-gray-300 mx-4 p-2">{project.title}</p>
                <div className="w-full h-72 relative m-8 p-4">
                    <Image
                        src={project.image}
                        alt={`Picture of the ${project.title}`}
                        layout='fill'
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="w-full mx-12 p-4 text-left text-indent flex-grow">
                    {project.description}
                </div>
                {project.languages?.map((language, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index} className="self-end flex gap-2 italic mr-8 mt-12 p-2 text-gray-600 text-sm">
                            {language}
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

It throws an `Excessive stack depth comparing types 'FlatArray<Arr, ?>' and 'FlatArray<Arr, ?>'` error. What might be the reason for that?

I ran into [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43249) which tells me to downgrade VSCode's used TS version, but is there any other solution that someone came up with?

Comment: Please share reproducable code

Comment: It is reproducable. What do you want me to add?

Comment: How is that reproducible? `ReferenceError: project is not defined` is not the error you're complaining about...

Comment: See edit, is it reproducable now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, TS version `4.3.0-dev` has an issue and I have to change the VSCode's used TS version to the `workspace` version which is `4.2.3`. Stumbled upon one or two other ways, but [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43249) was the only solution that works, unfortunately

#### Yay, found a different workaround

```
      <>
       {project.languages?.map((language, index) => {
         return (
           <div key={index} className="self-end flex gap-2 italic mr-8 mt-12 p-2 text-gray-600 text-sm">
              {language}
            </div>
          )
       })}
    </>
```

Apparently, adding fragments resolves the issue for now.